# Designing interface in ios

Tags: ios

I have a page which I have to design in ios.Page contains following things:

1. Banner Image(full width, 380 height).
2. A box which contains 6 line of text
3. A box of full width and 400 height contains Map
4. Continer which contain 4 images horizontally.
5. User Reviews which could be more than 100

Please suggest how to create above page in ios.Give me the overview of creating this page or any link.

Thank You

Comment: This is basically asking the community to do the work for you. Please be respectful and dig a little on your own.

Answer (score 1):

"iOS Human Interface Guidelines" - This is your solution at this moment https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/